# Looping CSS3 transition

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to loop a CSS3 transition, the idea is to add a class to the element to start the transition and listen to the transitionend event, when the event is fired I remove the class and start again.

```
var transition = function () {
    // add class to start the transition
    flipper.addClass('flipped');

    flipper.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function () {
        // remove class when transition is done
        flipper.removeClass('flipped');
        transition();
    });
}
```

Here is a [fiddle with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/hugogiusti/mRmSA/)

The problem is that it only runs the first time, when the class is added a second time the event is never fired.

Is there any other way to loop a transition?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question - please pay more attention in future.  The problematic code is shown clearly above, and there is a link to show the problem at work.  There's nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser is not getting chance to remove the class before you add it again, so it's not resetting the style.  Putting a 1ms delay in fixes it...

```
flipper.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function () {
    // remove class when transition is done
    $('#console').append('[removing class]');
    flipper.removeClass("flipped");
    setTimeout(function() {
        transition();
    }, 1);
});
```

**[Modified jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mRmSA/1/)**

**Note:**

You could pass `transition` as a parameter to the timeout call, like this...

```
setTimeout(transition, 1);
```

It's just a habit of mine to do it as I have above.